# Audio Plugin Implementation

Tags: ios, ipad, core-audio

Does anyone know about some sample code that illustrates the implementation of an audio plugin for iOS?

Comment: Are you asking about adding a custom audio unit to the graph?  Or just adding some audio processing in your own app?  You can't add any plugins or other processing to any app other than your own on stock iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

There was an AUPlugin.h header for iPhone SDK 3 that seemed to permit you to create your own audio units, which you could then put in an AUGraph.  But it apparently never worked, and all its functions (AudioComponentRegister(), etc.) were deprecated in iOS 4.

Basically, to do your own audio processing, you need to set up a render callback as a property of a single audio unit or somewhere in an AUGraph, and do your work in that callback function.

Comment: It looks like AudioComponentRegister() is back again in the `AudioComponent.h` (public) header file of iOS 5. Haven't tried using it though.